# Order of evaluation with curried function and map

Tags: scala, currying

I'm having some doubts over when curried functions are substituted, and how that may impact program performance.

Specifically, given the following code:

```scala
def curriedFun(f: Stuff => OtherStuff)(stuff: Stuff) = ...

def normalFun(stuff: Stuff): OtherStuff = ...

...

listOfListsOfStuff: List[Stuff] = ...

val otherStuff: List[OtherStuff] =
      listOfListsOfStuff.map(curriedFun(normalFun))
```

My doubt concerns the last call of the block, more specifically how `map` interacts with the curried function. In particular:

- Does the currying substitution happen only once? i.e. is the code equivalent, performance-wise, to this:

```scala
val substitutedFun = curriedFun(normalFun)
val otherStuff: List[OtherStuff] =
      listOfListsOfStuff.map(substitutedFun)
```

- Or is it substituted once for each element of the `otherStuff` list?

My intuition tells me it *should* be equivalent to substituting the function beforehand (the first option), but I can't really understand why, and I don't know where to look...

Comment: They are equivalent, but on your map the substitution is happening for each element. Anyways, you shouldn't worry for this, the difference in performance on both cases should be so small, that it wouldn't matter on normal cases, and usually you will have bigger problems. Additionally, probably the **JIT** will inline that on runtime, leaving the original code as the _"optimized"_ one.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez but wouldn't the substitution happen before the call to `map`, in which case it would only happen once? Your reply implies that the function is substituted _inside_ `map`

Comment: Oh right, in this case yes as Tim explained. Anyways, my point was more about the fact that you shouldn't worry about the performance of trivial things. Rather, write the code that is easier to understand and change. Then, and only then, profile the code, and optimize the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to a method are computed before the method is called (unless the argument is by-name). So the argument to  `map` is computed before `map` is called.

So in this case, `curriedFun(normalFun)` is computed once to give a function, and then this function is passed to `map`. `map` then applies this function to each element of `listOfListsOfStuff`. The fact that the argument to `map` is generate by a curried function is irrelevant to the order of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find `scala -print` often useful for these kinds of questions. For example, create the following `Main.scala` file

```
// Main.scala
def foo(i: Int)(j: String): String = j
List("hello", "world").map(foo(42))
```

and then execute `scala -print Main.scala` which outputs something like

```
def foo(i: Int, j: String): String = j;
def $anonfun$new$1(j: String): String = anon$1.this.foo(42, j);
new collection.immutable.::("hello", new collection.immutable.::("world", scala.collection.immutable.Nil)).$asInstanceOf[List]().map({
   ((j: String) => anon$1.this.$anonfun$new$1(j))
});
```

where we see currying is resolved once to `$anonfun$new$1` function before `map` executes.